# Akka, single mailbox multiple (identical) actors?

Tags: akka

I'm trying to make a very basic use of Akka, while being not really excited about slogging through all the extensive documentation.

I've got a working actor. It's stateless, but CPU intensive and long running. I'd like to have a small pool of these things, so that I can get more than a single message being processed at the same time (I have 8 cores, so 8 of these would seem like a possible choice).

My problem is that I have no idea where in the docs to even start looking. I guess I'd appreciate being "given a fish" (tell me how to do it), but at the same time, knowing where to look in the docs (teach me to fish) would be very valuable, likely more so, too.

---

In trying the suggestions to this point, I went with a router first, as it seemed easiest. However, as this sample shows, I don't think it solves my problem. Using the code below, some messages find their way into a mailbox  for an actor that doesn't become the first available.

```
package routeex

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props, Terminated}
import akka.routing.{ActorRefRoutee, RoundRobinRoutingLogic, Router, SmallestMailboxRoutingLogic}

case class Work(message: String, dur: Int = 0)

object Worker {
  private val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
  private var nextId = 1
  def getMyId: Int = {
    val id = nextId
    nextId += 1
    id
  }
  def timestamp: String = f"${System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime}%6.3f"
}

class Worker extends Actor {
  val myId = Worker.getMyId
  println(s"making actor, id is $myId")

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Work("slow", delay) => {
      println(s"${Worker.timestamp} Actor $myId going slow for $delay...")
      Thread.sleep(delay)
      println(s"${Worker.timestamp} Actor $myId awake again...")
    }
    case Work("report", _) => println(s"${Worker.timestamp} Actor $myId reporting for duty!")
    case m => println(s"${Worker.timestamp} Actor $myId got unexpected message $m")
  }
}

class Master extends Actor {
  var router = {
    val routees = Vector.fill(2) {
      val r = context.actorOf(Props[Worker])
      context watch r
      ActorRefRoutee(r)
    }
//    Router(RoundRobinRoutingLogic(), routees)
    Router(SmallestMailboxRoutingLogic(), routees)
  }

  def receive = {
    case w: Work =>
      router.route(w, sender())
    case Terminated(a) =>
      router = router.removeRoutee(a)
      val r = context.actorOf(Props[Worker])
      context watch r
      router = router.addRoutee(r)
  }
}

object TryIt {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem.create("System")
    val m = system.actorOf(Props[Master])

    m ! Work("slow", 10000)
    m ! Work("slow", 1000)
    m ! Work("slow", 1000)
    m ! Work("slow", 1000)
    m ! Work("report")
    m ! Work("report")
    m ! Work("report")
    m ! Work("report")

    Thread.sleep(30000)
    system.terminate()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re looking for a *router*: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/routing.html

Comment: This looks possible. Can I confirm something: I want the "first available" actor to pull the next message. The nearest behavior I see in the note you liked to looks  like it routes based on "smallest mailbox" but just because a mailbox is empty doesn't correlate to an actor that's idle and therefore ready to work.

Will I / can I get that kind of behavior? I would normally do this with an ExecutorService (as in Java) but I'm trying to change paradigms ;)

Comment: With the SmallestMailboxPool it will pick a routee in this order:
1) pick any idle routee (not processing message) with empty mailbox
2) pick any routee with empty mailbox
3) pick routee with fewest pending messages in mailbox.

So it is going to pick an available actor if there is, and only if there aren't it will pick the one with the smallest mailbox.

Comment: I've added a code example, which I believe illustrates that the router (while simple, and "not bad") doesn't give me the behavior I want. It seems that some messages are put into a mailbox of an actor that isn't yet available, and doesn't become available first.

Comment: That’s right, at the moment you send all the messages, the routees are just the same and get half the messages each. If the tasks arrive progressively it may work but if they arrive all at the same time it’s not efficient. Then I guess the best is having a supervisor actor distributing the work and have the workers notify when they’re ready.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the "first available" actor to pull the next message.

Based on your comment above, a router is not what you want. Instead, consider using the "work pulling" pattern. The gist of this pattern is:

- A master actor coordinates units of work among a number of worker actors.
- Workers register themselves to the master, meaning that workers can be added or removed dynamically.
- When the master receives work to be done, the master notifies the workers that work is available. Workers pull units of work when they're ready, do what needs to be done with their respective units of work, then ask the master for more work when they're finished.

The following links, which are listed in the Akka [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/howto.html), describe this pattern:

- The original post (by Derek Wyatt): http://letitcrash.com/post/29044669086/balancing-workload-across-nodes-with-akka-2
- A follow-on post (by Michael Pollmeier): http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/akka-work-pulling-pattern

You could adapt [Pollmeier's implementation](https://github.com/mpollmeier/akka-patterns/blob/master/src/main/scala/akkapatterns/WorkPullingPattern.scala) for your needs.

Comment: Interesting stuff. Pollmeier says: "This post is about two years old now - please consider it only as nice reading material to learn about distributed work patterns. [...]"

Since this seems like something that's really simple in a single queue (mail-box) multiple actor type scenario, as might easily (if orthogonally to Akka itself) be implemented using a simple worker pool, should I just go and do my own thing, perhaps?

It might also be done reasonably cleanly using a Promise/Future approach (though both of these proposals end up creating more threads).